# Magento 2.3.4 product videos not showing on frontend slider

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have added/updated product videos in my Magento 2.3.4. The videos are showing on the admin side. But on the frontend, the videos are not showing. It is not even coming in the slider. It was working earlier. After updating the video URL or adding a new video it is not showing. I have printed the data of `$block->getGalleryImagesJson()`. In that, the path for `thumb` in the video has a path, but when I tried that path in the browser it returned a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you clear the cache? Try reindex and clear the cache to see if it works.

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Tried. Not working